# How to increase the font size of automatic created window

Tags: configuration

I am using MMA 12.3.0 on Ubuntu 18.04. I changed a new screen and the font of the toolbar became very small compared to other applications and managed to solve that. But, the font in the automatic created window is still very small compared to notebook font and toolbar font, see red arrow in the below picture. How can I increase this font  size?

[image]